# Vb.net Randomising unique buttons set of buttons?

Tags: vb.net, image, button, random

I am trying to create a login system for a touch pannel, The system **shows 4 images in random order** these images include a Circle, a Suare, a Triangle, and a Hexagon. The reason for displaying the images at random is to prevent the next user from identifying the previous login by finger prints left on the screen. **Each of these four images may only be displayed once**. I have got a working system and it is random but not random enougth the oreder of patters is frequently repeated and the last image is almost allways a Hexagon. Dose anybody know a better way of programming what I need?

```
       Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

#Region "Create security login buttons in random order"

#Region "Generating randomisation"

        Dim random As New Random()

        Dim FirstButton As Integer
        Dim SecondButton As Integer
        Dim ThirdButton As Integer
        Dim FourthButton As Integer

#Region "Sets random value for FirstButton"

        FirstButton = Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 3))

#End Region

#Region "Sets random value for SecondButton"

        Do While SecondButton = FirstButton
            SecondButton = Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 3))
        Loop

#End Region

#Region "Sets random value for ThirdButton"
        Do While ThirdButton = FirstButton Or ThirdButton = SecondButton
            ThirdButton = Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 3))
        Loop

#End Region

#Region "Sets random value for FourthButton"

        Dim AssignValZero As Integer = 0
        Dim AssignValOne As Integer = 1
        Dim AssignValTwo As Integer = 2
        Dim AssignValThree As Integer = 3

        If AssignValZero = FirstButton Or SecondButton Or ThirdButton Then
            If AssignValOne = FirstButton Or SecondButton Or ThirdButton Then
                If AssignValTwo = FirstButton Or SecondButton Or ThirdButton Then
                    If AssignValThree = FirstButton Or SecondButton Or ThirdButton Then
                        FourthButton = AssignValThree
                    End If
                Else
                    FourthButton = AssignValTwo
                End If
            Else
                FourthButton = AssignValOne
            End If
        Else
            FourthButton = AssignValZero
        End If

#End Region

#End Region

#Region "Creating actual buttons"

#Region "Create SquareButton"

        Dim SquareButton As Button = New Button
        Dim ButtonSpacer As Integer = 12

        SquareButton.Height = 150
        SquareButton.Width = 100
        SquareButton.Image = My.Resources.Square

        If FirstButton = 0 Then
            SquareButton.Location = New Point((0 * SquareButton.Width) + (1 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FirstButton = 1 Then
            SquareButton.Location = New Point((1 * SquareButton.Width) + (2 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FirstButton = 2 Then
            SquareButton.Location = New Point((2 * SquareButton.Width) + (3 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FirstButton = 3 Then
            SquareButton.Location = New Point((3 * SquareButton.Width) + (4 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        End If

        Me.Controls.Add(SquareButton)

#End Region

#Region "Create RoundButton"

        Dim RoundButton As Button = New Button

        RoundButton.Height = 150
        RoundButton.Width = 100
        RoundButton.Image = My.Resources.Circle

        If SecondButton = 0 Then
            RoundButton.Location = New Point((0 * RoundButton.Width) + (1 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf SecondButton = 1 Then
            RoundButton.Location = New Point((1 * RoundButton.Width) + (2 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf SecondButton = 2 Then
            RoundButton.Location = New Point((2 * RoundButton.Width) + (3 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf SecondButton = 3 Then
            RoundButton.Location = New Point((3 * RoundButton.Width) + (4 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        End If

        Me.Controls.Add(RoundButton)

#End Region

#Region "Create TriangleButton"

        Dim TriangleButton As Button = New Button

        TriangleButton.Height = 150
        TriangleButton.Width = 100
        TriangleButton.Image = My.Resources.Triangle

        If ThirdButton = 0 Then
            TriangleButton.Location = New Point((0 * TriangleButton.Width) + (1 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf ThirdButton = 1 Then
            TriangleButton.Location = New Point((1 * TriangleButton.Width) + (2 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf ThirdButton = 2 Then
            TriangleButton.Location = New Point((2 * TriangleButton.Width) + (3 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf ThirdButton = 3 Then
            TriangleButton.Location = New Point((3 * TriangleButton.Width) + (4 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        End If

        Me.Controls.Add(TriangleButton)

#End Region

#Region "Create HexagonButton"

        Dim OctagonButton As Button = New Button

        OctagonButton.Height = 150
        OctagonButton.Width = 100
        OctagonButton.Image = My.Resources.Hexagon

        If FourthButton = 0 Then
            OctagonButton.Location = New Point((0 * OctagonButton.Width) + (1 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FourthButton = 1 Then
            OctagonButton.Location = New Point((1 * OctagonButton.Width) + (2 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FourthButton = 2 Then
            OctagonButton.Location = New Point((2 * OctagonButton.Width) + (3 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        ElseIf FourthButton = 3 Then
            OctagonButton.Location = New Point((3 * OctagonButton.Width) + (4 * ButtonSpacer), 25)
        End If

        Me.Controls.Add(OctagonButton)

#End Region

#End Region

#End Region

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you always want the buttons in the same positions, but which button is in which position would change, then I'd recommend implementing a shuffle to randomize them.  Look for "Fisher-Yates shuffle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overcomplicated this greatly. Just create all four `Buttons` in the designer, complete with images, and add them to a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` to get the layout you want. At run time, you can move the `Buttons` to random positions with little code. Here's an example that works with a `TableLayoutPanel`:

```vb
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Get a list of the Buttons in the container.
    Dim buttons = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Cast(Of Button)().ToArray()

    'Get a full list of the cell positions of the Buttons and randomise it.
    Dim cellPositions = buttons.Select(Function(b) TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(b)).
                                OrderBy(Function(tlpcp) rng.NextDouble()).
                                ToArray()

    'Assign the random cell positions back to the Buttons.
    For i = 0 To buttons.GetUpperBound(0)
        TableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(buttons(i), cellPositions(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's an even simpler example that works with a `FlowLayoutPanel`:

```vb
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim buttons = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.
                                   Cast(Of Button)().
                                   OrderBy(Function(b) rng.NextDouble()).
                                   ToArray()

    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(buttons)
End Sub
```

Just be aware that the Tab order for the `Buttons` will not change when their order changes using that code. You'd need something more to change that.